# Worst case one way function

Tags: one-way-function

the worst-case one way function is defined as follows
$$\forall A \exists x : pr(A(f(x))\in f^{-1}(f(x)))\neq 1$$
can you give any example of such function?

Comment: This is probably just me not understanding the notation, but represents $f^{-1}$ all possible values if somebody *does* try to reverse the function?

Comment: Yeah, actually A is an advetsary who tries to find a pre-image for y (where y=f(x))

Comment: The more usual notion of an (average-case) one-way function is, naturally, also a worst-case one-way function. See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_function#Candidates_for_one-way_functions

Comment: Thanks but I mean a function which is worst-case one way but not weak or strong(average-case) one way. do you have any idea about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Worst-case one-way functions exist if and only if P ≠ NP, therefore, if I were you, I would not expect to get a definitive answer to your question any time soon :).

On the other hand, if you are willing to assume that P ≠ NP, then it is not hard to construct such a function (that is actually exactly a half of the proof of the theorem I stated in the previous paragraph).